# better approach to mocking functions that need to consume arguments directly

Tags: c++, googletest

I am mocking a C library (..ughh) containing functions that take as argument "structs with pointers". My goal is to do some expectations on the data these pointers are pointing to. The library functions immediate consume their arguments. i.e. these structs can go out of scope after the function is callled.

in code:

```
struct A
{
    B* somePointer;
}

class ClassUnderTest
{
public:
    ClassUnderTest()
    {
        B arbitraryStruct;
        A structArg;
        structArg.somePointer = &arbitraryStruct;
        C_LibraryFunction(&A);
    }
};
```

my solution is to save the argument by defining an gtest 'action'. in this action save arbritraryStruct to some global and do my expectation magic. e.g.

```
B arbitraryStruct;
ACTION(captureB)
{
  const A* a= arg0;
  arbitraryStruct = *a->somePointer;
}

Test(TestClassUnderTest, testIt)
{
  EXPECT_CALL(clibrary, 
  C_libraryFunction(testing::_)).WillOnce(DoAll(captureB());
  ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

  EXPECT_EQ(bla, B.arbitraryStruct);
}
```

it works, but it feels a little comprehensive. There are allot of calls of that lib that i need to mock and some contain complex structures. As a lazy programmer it feels like this can be done in a better way. can anybody come up with a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A better way is **not** to do it. Instead, you should create a class using those functions, and mock that class instead. This class should be as simple as possible, in order to prevent possible bugs.

For example:

```
struct MyIface {
  virtual ~MyIface(){}

  virtual void Clog() = 0;
};

struct VeebleFitzer {
  VeebleFitzer() : a( funcA() ) {
  }
  virtual void Clog() {
    funcX( a );
    funcY();
  }

  int a;
};
```

Then use some kind of dependency injection to pass objects to wherever they are needed.

---

You can always create functional tests, where you use real resources (including "real", and not mock, functions), to test your code.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! your totally right, its way cleaner to define an interface to abstract away a external component, (in my case a vulkan API). Now i think of it, what i am trying to do is to actually put that "conversion layer" under test as well. maybe not a good idea to continue this path... the challenge here is that performance on some parts is really key and im not sure i can keep it simple in this area, but that is another discussion

Comment: @SvenRademakers It depends what you want to do. The functional tests should do what you want - write tests with gtest using real functions (don't mock them). If you want to test functionality above, then unit tests and mock functionality below.